# how do I throw an error for a site.com guest user

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, error-messages

I am trying to throw an error for a site.com guest user but I am not getting any exception what am I missing?

Apex:

```
public class webToCareerAttachments {
    private final Career__c webCareer;
    public List<Attachment> attachments {get; set;} 
    public List<Attachment> newAttachments {get; set;}
    public webToCareerAttachments(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        webCareer = (Career__c)stdController.getRecord();
        id RTid = [SELECT CareerApplicant__c FROM RecordtypeId__c][0].CareerApplicant__c;
        if(RTId !=null){
            webCareer.RecordTypeId = RTId;
        }
        newAttachments=new List<Attachment>{new Attachment()};
    }
    public PageReference saveLead() {
        try {
            insert(webCareer);
          List<ContentDocumentLink> doc = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = :webCareer.id];
            system.debug('doc: '+doc);
            if( doc.size()!=null){
               save(webCareer.id);   
            }else{
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please add a CV'));
            }
        }
        catch(System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
            return null;
        }
        PageReference p = new PageReference('https://www.google.com/');
        p.setRedirect(true);
        return p;
    }
    // retrieve the existing attachments
    public List<Attachment> getAttachments()
    {
        // only execute the SOQL if the list hasn't been initialised
        if (null==attachments)
        {
            attachments=[select Id, ParentId, Name, Description from Attachment where parentId=:webCareer.id];
        }
        return attachments;
    }
    public void addMore()
    {
        // append idx< NUM ATTACHMENTS to the attachments list
        for (Integer idx=0; idx<1; idx++)
        {
            newAttachments.add(new Attachment());
        }
    }    
    public void save(id pId)
    {
        List<Attachment> toInsert=new List<Attachment>();
        list<ContentVersion> vList = new list<ContentVersion>();
        for (Attachment newAtt : newAttachments)
        {
            if (newAtt.Body!=null)
            {
                ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
                v.versionData = newAtt.body;
                v.title = newAtt.name;
                v.FirstPublishLocationId = pId;
                v.pathOnClient = newAtt.name;          
                v.Description = newAtt.name;
                vList.add(v);             
            }else{
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
            }
        }
        insert vList; 
        newAttachments.clear();
        attachments=null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do you have the message component on your vf page

Comment: @Eric I have it as follows <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>

Comment: Does the guest user profile have access to the page, the class and the object? If so, I recommend you create a Unit Test where a guest user is the RunAs User. That should quickly help you determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: @crmprogdev if I am not wrong , System.runAs only considers record sharing in place and doesn't respect FLS permissions for that user.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal You would be incorrect. RunAs does consider Object Level and FLS which is exactly why you would want to use it. This is in fact one of the ways you can test your org's security as well as create positive/negative test scenarios to assert that UserA can access records while UserB cannot, etc.

Comment: @crmprogdev strange. Docs say something else. The system method runAs enables you to write test methods that change the user context to an existing user or a new user so that the user’s record sharing is enforced. The runAs method doesn’t enforce user permissions or field-level permissions, only record sharing.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal If the user created for the RunAs user doesn't have the necessary permissions, errors will be thrown. Apex will respect those permissions in the unit test. As an example, a sites user won't be able to call code to create records they don't have access to when they're a RunAs user. The records simply will not be created. That is the way it has always worked for me.

Comment: @crmprogdev The guest user has acces to all of these. I did a debugging as guest uses but this is not throwing any errors.